# Pictures not centered in carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I made a carousel using twitter-bootstrap, and it shows a couple pictures. Problem is, all of the pictures are different sizes and, right now, they aren't centered. Is there a way that the carousel can re-size to center each picture horizontally and vertically whenever the picture in question changes?

Here is code so far:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div id="picture-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#picture-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#picture-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#picture-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="/images/picture-1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/picture-2.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/picture-3.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#picture-carousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#picture-carousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div> <!--Carousel-->
</div> <!--modal-body-->
```

Thanks for any and all tips!

Comment: difficult to say anything without jsfiddle or css!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Style to center images :-

```
div.carousel-inner img{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```